Consistent Artifacts in Android ImageView with Camera Preview
I'm working on an application for the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) using the source code from an SOM provider and facing a challenging issue with the camera preview. When using SurfaceView alongside the Camera class, the preview is clear. However, when the preview data is displayed in an ImageView via the Camera class's onPreviewFrame callback, consistent line artifacts appear. These lines seem to be remnants from previous frames.

The image can be divided into five equal vertical sections. In higher resolutions, these line artifacts appear only in the first vertical quadrant of each section. They are equally spaced and appear at consistent locations within this quadrant, though not every artifact is present in every frame, leading to what appears as random spacing horizontally. When I decrease the resolution by half, these artifacts span across the entire horizontal space of each section, although the five-section division remains apparent.
Here's the code segment for setting up the camera preview:
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.testapp.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CameraTestFragment extends Fragment implements Camera.PreviewCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private View root;

    private SurfaceView surfacePreview;

    private ImageView testPreview;

    private Camera camera;

    private boolean isActive;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera_test, container, false);

        surfacePreview = root.findViewById(R.id.surface_preview_capture);
        testPreview = root.findViewById(R.id.testPreview);

        surfacePreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);

        updateVideoPreview(surfacePreview.getHolder());

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        if(camera != null){
            isActive = false;
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        if(isActive) {
            Camera.Size  previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,previewSize.width,previewSize.height),100,out);
            byte[] jpegData = out.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegData, 0, jpegData.length);
            testPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.d("VideoPreviewHandler",  "surfaceChanged");
        updateVideoPreview(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d("VideoPreviewHandler",  "surfaceDestroyed");

    }

    public void updateVideoPreview(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Log.d("VideoPreviewHandler",  "surfaceDestroyed");

        camera = Camera.open();

        if (camera != null) {

            try {

                Camera.Parameters cp = camera.getParameters();
                cp.setPreviewSize(640, 360);
                cp.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
                cp.setPreviewFpsRange(60, 60);
                try {
                    camera.setParameters(cp);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.d("RuntimeException", e.getMessage());
                }

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
                camera.startPreview();

                isActive = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateVideoPreview(surfacePreview.getHolder());
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

}

My questions are:

Why is there a significant difference between the output on SurfaceView, and ImageView whose image created by using data from the onPreviewFrame callback function, given that the latter exhibits these artifacts?
How is image data processed differently in these two approaches within the AOSP codebase?
What might be causing these artifacts to appear consistently in the same locations and in a pattern dependent on the resolution, and how could I go about resolving them?

I've developed a partial map that tracks the flow of data through the source code. Although I tried updating questionable sections using different code sources, the issues persist. I also experimented with adjusting the image format, frame rate, and resolution, but none of these changes resolved the problems
